# Search parameter in stored procedure not functioning

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I'm trying to create a stored procedure in SQL Server 2008 that searches the ([Chinook](http://chinookdatabase.codeplex.com/), if it helps) database's Track table for tracks that match a (part of) an album title. For example, when the parameter is "rock", I'd like to see all the tracks that are on albums that have titles with "rock" in them someplace.

Hard-coding 'rock' works as expected, but running the procedure from Management Studio with 'rock' as the parameter returns a lot of non-"rock" results.

Here is the script I am using to tinker with my stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[searchTrackAlbumTitle]
    @trackAlbumTitle nvarchar
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT Track.TrackId
      ,Track.Name AS TrackName
      ,Artist.Name AS ArtistName
      ,Album.Title AS AlbumTitle
      ,Track.Composer
      ,Track.Milliseconds
      ,Track.Bytes
      ,MediaType.Name AS TypeName
      ,Genre.Name AS GenreName
      ,Track.UnitPrice
    FROM Track
        LEFT JOIN Album ON Track.AlbumId = Album.AlbumId
        LEFT JOIN Artist ON Album.ArtistId = Artist.ArtistId
        LEFT JOIN MediaType ON Track.MediaTypeId = MediaType.MediaTypeId
        LEFT JOIN Genre ON Track.GenreId = Genre.GenreId
    WHERE Album.Title LIKE ( '%' + @trackAlbumTitle + '%' ) -- doesn't work
    --WHERE Album.Title LIKE ( '%' + 'rock' + '%' ) -- works

END
```

Comment: I bet all the `non-"rock" results` contain an `r`.

Comment: Also this silent truncation might have been identified much more quickly by adding simple debug 101 to the beginning of the procedure, e.g. `PRINT @trackAlbumTitle;` would have yielded `r`.

Comment: Thanks. That idea is new to me, but I tried it now and I see that I can tab over to "Messages" to see the results.

Comment: You can also `SELECT @trackAlbumTitle;`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a length on your parameter. e.g.

```
@trackAlbumTitle NVARCHAR(255)
```

Right now it's being truncated to `NVARCHAR(1)`. [See this blog post for more info](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - it applies to `NVARCHAR`, too.

Also note that if you say `WHERE Album.anything` the `LEFT JOIN` becomes an `INNER JOIN`. So you should either move it to the `ON` clause or change the join to an explicit `INNER JOIN`. Right now it's confusing - I don't know which behavior you want (and they are different).

Comment: Thanks! As I was attempting Mr. Danev's suggestion, I hovered over the parameter and saw that it was nvarchar(1) (whoops). I guess it was searching for all albums including the first letter. And thanks for the information about the joins!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 WHERE Album.Title LIKE ( '%' + rtrim(@trackAlbumTitle) + '%' )
```

Comment: Thanks for the the suggestion. I guess the problem really was that I didn't specify a length in the first place. Hovering over my parameter after LIKE, I saw that it was nvarchar(1)!